# Why the memory is still holding when I do removefromsuperview?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm currently working on a ipad project and found this.
so here is my structure

i subclassed uiviewcontroller as customizedVC,like this

```
@protocol customizedVCDelegate

-(void)viewclosed:(UIView *)view oldviewcontroller:(UIViewController *)oldvc newvcname:(UIViewController *)newvc;

@end


@interface customizedVC : UIViewController {
    id <customizedVCDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <customizedVCDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

in demoipadappDelegate, that is the backbone for switching views, i took the protocol and implemented the viewclosed function.
I got a lot of views, each view will be loaded from nib. so i load the first one in demoipadappDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //loading openvinview
    openingVC *vc = [[openingVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"openingview" bundle:nil];
    vc.delegate = self; 
    [window addSubview:vc.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

to switch views, i will fire the viewClosed in each viewcontroller. for example, i got VC1 and want to swtich to VC2. i fire a viewClosed in vc1. and since vc1's delegate is demoipadappDelegate, infact all vc's delegate is demoipadappDelegate. so the demoipadappDelegate will received the event and do this. this is in demoipadappDelegate

```
-(void)viewclosed:(UIView *)view oldviewcontroller:(UIViewController *)oldvc newvcname:(UIViewController *)newvc;
{

    self.currentVC = (customizedVC *)newvc;
    self.currentVC.delegate = self;
    [window addSubview:self.currentVC.view];

    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [oldvc release];

}
```

I expected that the memery usage would drop. it didn't.
I also checked that in each vc, I've already manually release anything i alloc. so that's not the case.

sorry for my poor english, i hope that i had explained clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're using the right casing?

The method is called [`removeFromSuperview`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCBEIDB), not `removefromsuperview`.

Comment: yes, the casing was right, not caused by spelling, but thanks anyway